# Java Enable/Disable Button

Tags: java

I'm creating a game that uses buttons. I want to disable a button once it's been selected, so that it cannot again until the game has restarted, but I'm having trouble achieving this. Could some let me know how to go about doing this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                        if (q==2) {
                        label2.setText("Correct!"); }
                        else {
                            label2.setText("Wrong!!");
                    }}
```

Comment: Can you please create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That can help the reader who is trying to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the source of the event from the `ActionEvent` with `getSource`. Then cast it to the correct type, and disable it with `setEnabled`

Here's an example, assuming you're using `JButton`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if (q==2) {
        label2.setText("Correct!"); 
    } else {
        label2.setText("Wrong!!");
    }

    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
        ((JButton)e.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you re-enable the buttons once the correct one has been selected?

Comment: @user3490456 Call `setEnabled` on each one. Either store them all in a data structure when you create them (which will be the easier way), or use their parent's `getComponents` method.

Answer (score 0):

Call `button.setEnabled(false)` to disable it, and `button.setEnabled(true)` to reinstate it.

Answer (score 0):

What's the trouble? I trust you've taken a look at the JButton documentation (assuming you're using JButtons). Using this function will allow you to enable/disable buttons.

[JButton.setEnabled(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setEnabled())